# strange results from transmitter radiation calculation

Tags: power, transmitter, radiation

This table was taken from:http://www.emfwise.com/distance.php

[image]

At that site a formula:
Power Density = P/4Πr2 
was used in order to calculate the power density(mW/m2)
according to the distance from the transmitter.
On that table the transmit power of the transmitter
is 30mW and you can see how the power density decrease
in according to the distance from the transmitter.
When i used the formula(Power Density = P/4Πr2) 
to calculate the power density in according to the distance that
shown in the table,all the results are ok(as in the table).

For example:
30/4Π(0.3*0.3) =~26.5mW/m2

30/4Π(5*5) =~0.100mW/m2(~100uW/m2).etc.

But when i used a distance that less than 30cm,
i got a power density results that higher than the transmitted 
power of the transmitter itself and this result doesn't make sense.

For example:
30/4Π(0.2*0.2) =~60mW/m2.

Why do i get that strange results?
and how can i calculate power density at distance less than
30cm,that won't give me strange results?

Comment: 1st THERES NO NEED TO YELL

Comment: WHY ARE WE YELLING?!

Comment: @mARCUSmÜLLER: MAYBE SOMEONE HAS A BROKEN cAPS LOCK KEY?

Comment: @PlasmAhh: wE SHALL NEvvvvver KNOW !!!111!1eleven!one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if the area of the surface of the sphere is less then 1m^2 it is entirely valid for the power density to be greater then the transmitted power. 
A one watt laser beam hitting an area 1cm^2 has a power density of 10kw/m^2, expand that bean to cover a square meter and it has a power density of 1w/m^2, expand to 1000m^2 and you are down to 1mw/m^2 In each case the total power is 1W, its just as the area falls the power density rises.

Secondly, P/(4Pi R^2) only applies in the far field, which is to say once the radiation source can be approximated as a point (Or equivalently that the wavefront approximates a spherical rather then cylindrical wave). 
You don't say what frequency this is, I am guessing at 2.4GHz where the wavelength is ~12cm, which assuming say 10 wavelengths for getting into the far field means that anything closer then 1.2M is going to be wrong because the emitter is not a point, the calculations become horribly more complicated for this case, it gets even worse when antennas have gain....

Also I thought the RF exposure limits were specified in terms of electric field strength, not power, at least in the HF bands, maybe it is different in the microwave bands?

Comment: So,how at a distance less than 1 square meter(when i add in the formula a distance between 29cm to 100cm),i still got a result that lower than 30mW/m2?    Only when i use in the formula a distance that lower than 29cm,the result gets higher than 30mW/m2.

Comment: Distances are in meters, AREAS are in square meters. Once the area of the surface of the sphere around the radiator drops to below one square meter, then the power density in watts per meter square MUST rise above the input power because all that power is now covering an area smaller then one square meter. Once R becomes smaller then sqrt (1/(4 Pi)) = 0.28m the area becomes smaller then 1 square meter.

Answer (score 2):

**Units, pay attention to the units.**

If a transmitter puts out 30 **mW**, and you caculate **mW/m2** on a surface that is **less than 1 square meter**, it is hardly surprising that the mW/m2 is higher than the transmitter output, which is bare **watts**, not **watts per meter squared**.

More simply, the results make perfect sense.

Following comments: Area of a sphere is 4•Pi•r•r

So a sphere with area of one square meter is: 1=4•Pi•r•r

or 1/(4•Pi) = r•r

so

squareroot[1/(4•Pi)] = r

and r is thus 0.282094791773882 (in meters)

Comment: So,how at a distance less than 1 square meter(when i add in the formula a distance between 29cm to 100cm),i still got a result that lower than 30mW/m2?    Only when i use in the formula a distance that lower than 29cm,the result gets higher than 30mW/m2.

Comment: ...because you are not solid on math? A sphere with surface area of 1 square meter has a radius of 0.282 meter (ignoring the 5th decimal place and beyond) or 28.2 cm - a sphere with 100 cm (1 m) radius has an area of 12.566 square meters.